# React I have an endless loop rendering my edit component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, redux-toolkit

I have two components. My dashbord-component, in which I am dispatching the getAllDropDownRessort, which triggers the findAll function in my dropdownRessortSlice and an edit-component, in which I am dispatching the getDropdownRessort, which triggers the findOne function in the same slice.
When I calling the edit-component, it not ends rendering, and the redux-devtools tell me that it always renders the findAll function.
Thanks for your help.

Here is my dashbord-component:

```
const DropdownRessorts = () => {
  //bring in
  const {dropdownRessort, isLoading, isError, message} = useSelector((state)=>state.dropdownRessort);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(isError){
      console.log(message);
    }
    dispatch(getAllDropdownRessort());

    return ()=>{
      dispatch(reset());
    }
  }, [dispatch, isError, message]);
//bring out
  const [formdata, setFormdata] = useState(
    {
      lis:[],
      videos:[
        {
          iframe:"",
          ressort:"",
          timestamp:"",
          theme:"",
          title:""
      },
      {
          iframe:"",
          ressort:"",
          timestamp:"",
          theme:"",
          title:""
      },
      {
          iframe:"",
          ressort:"",
          timestamp:"",
          theme:"",
          title:""
      }
      ],
      themen:[],
    }
  );
    const {lis, videos,themen} = formdata;
    
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
      setFormdata((prevState)=>({
        ...prevState,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      }))
    }

    const onSubmit = (e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      const dropdownRessortData = {
        lis,
        videos,
        themen,
      }
      dispatch(createDropdownRessort(dropdownRessortData));
    }
    if(isLoading){
      return <Spinner/>
    }
  return (
    <Container>
            <CrudTitleHolder>
              <CrudTitle>Dropdown Menü Ressort</CrudTitle>
            </CrudTitleHolder>
            <DataformDropDownRessort onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              {dropdownRessort.length > 0 && <DataHolder>
                {dropdownRessort.map((item)=>(
                  <div key={item._id}>
                    {console.log(item._id)}
                         <h4 id="name">{item.name}</h4>
                      <div id="listenpunkte">Menüpunkte: {item.lis.join(", ")}<span style={{color:"var(--red)"}}> Bitte nur nach Absprache verändern.</span></div>
                      <VideoWrapper>
                        <DataVideoholder>
                          <iframe src={item.videos[0].iframe} title={item.videos[0].title}/>
                          <h4>{item.videos[0].ressort}</h4>
                          <h4>{item.videos[0].theme}</h4>
                          <p>{item.videos[0].title}</p>
                        </DataVideoholder>
                        <DataVideoholder>
                          <iframe src={item.videos[1].iframe} title={item.videos[0].title}/>
                          <h4>{item.videos[1].ressort}</h4>
                          <h4>{item.videos[1].theme}</h4>
                          <p>{item.videos[1].title}</p>
                        </DataVideoholder>
                        <DataVideoholder>
                          <iframe src={item.videos[2].iframe} title={item.videos[0].title}/>
                          <h4>{item.videos[2].ressort}</h4>
                          <h4>{item.videos[2].theme}</h4>
                          <p>{item.videos[2].title}</p>
                        </DataVideoholder>
                        </VideoWrapper>
                        <Themen>Themen: {item.themen.join(", ")}</Themen>
                    <DataButtonHolder>
                          <Link to={`/dropdownressortedit/${item._id}`}className="link"> 
                      <DataUpdateButton>Update</DataUpdateButton>
                      </Link>
                      <DataDeleteButton onClick={()=>dispatch(deleteDropdownRessort(item._id))}>Löschen</DataDeleteButton>
                    </DataButtonHolder>
                  </div>
                ))}
                </DataHolder>}

                <section className="menupoints" encType="multipart/form-data">
                  <DataLabel htmlFor="lis_ressorts">Menüpunkte Ressorts</DataLabel>
                  <DataInput type="text" name="lis_ressorts" id="lis_ressorts" value={lis} onChange={handleChange}/>
                </section>
                <div className="videos">
                    <section className="video_1">
                    <DataLabel htmlFor="ressortvideo_1_iframe">Video 1</DataLabel>
                    <DataInput type="file" name="ressortvideo_1_iframe" id="video_1_iframe" 
                    style={{background:"var(--blue)", color:"var(--white)"}}
                    value={videos[0].iframe}  onChange={handleChange}/>

                    <DataLabel htmlFor="video_1_ressort">Video 1 Ressortzuordnung</DataLabel>
                    <DataInput type="text" name="video_1_ressort" id="video_1_ressort" value={videos[0].ressort} onChange={handleChange}/>

                    <DataLabel htmlFor="video_1_theme">Video 1 Themenzuordnung</DataLabel>
                    <DataInput type="text" name="video_1_theme" id="video_1_theme"  value={videos[0].theme} onChange={handleChange}/>

                    <DataLabel htmlFor="video_1_title">Video 1 Titelzuordnung</DataLabel>
                    <DataInput type="text" name="video_1_title" id="video_1_title"  value={videos[0].title} onChange={handleChange}/>
                    </section>

                    <section className="video_2">
                      <DataLabel htmlFor="ressortvideo_2_iframe">Video 2</DataLabel>
                      <DataInput type="file" name="ressortvideo_2_iframe" id="video_2_iframe" 
                      style={{background:"var(--blue)", color:"var(--white)"}}
                      value={videos[1].iframe} onChange={handleChange}/>

                      <DataLabel htmlFor="video_2_ressort">Video 2 Ressortzuordnung</DataLabel>
                      <DataInput type="text" name="video_1_ressort" id="video_2_ressort"  value={videos[1].ressort} onChange={handleChange}/>

                      <DataLabel htmlFor="video_2_theme">Video 2 Themenzuordnung</DataLabel>
                      <DataInput type="text" name="video_2_theme" id="video_2_theme" value={videos[1].theme} onChange={handleChange}/>

                      <DataLabel htmlFor="video_2_title">Video 2 Titelzuordnung</DataLabel>
                      <DataInput type="text" name="video_2_title" id="video_2_title" value={videos[1].title} onChange={handleChange}/>
                    </section>
                    <section className="video_3">
                      <DataLabel htmlFor="ressortvideo_3_iframe">Video 3</DataLabel>
                      <DataInput type="file" name="ressortvideo_3_iframe" id="video_3_iframe" 
                      style={{background:"var(--blue)", color:"var(--white)"}}
                      value={videos[2].iframe} onChange={handleChange}/>

                      <DataLabel htmlFor="video_3_ressort">Video 3 Ressortzuordnung</DataLabel>
                      <DataInput type="text" name="video_3_ressort" id="video_3_ressort"  value={videos[2].ressort} onChange={handleChange}/>

                      <DataLabel htmlFor="video_3_theme">Video 3 Themenzuordnung</DataLabel>
                      <DataInput type="text" name="video_3_theme" id="video_3_theme"  value={videos[2].theme} onChange={handleChange}/>

                      <DataLabel htmlFor="video_3_title">Video 3 Titelzuordnung</DataLabel>
                      <DataInput type="text" name="video_3_title" id="video_3_title"  value={videos[2].title} onChange={handleChange}/>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <section className="themen">
                  <DataLabel htmlFor="themen_ressorts">Themen</DataLabel>
                  <DataInput type="text" name="themen_ressorts" id="themen_ressorts" value={themen} onChange={handleChange}/>
                </section>
                <DataButtonHolder>
                  <DataSendButton type="submit">Absenden</DataSendButton>
                  </DataButtonHolder>
            </DataformDropDownRessort>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default DropdownRessorts
```

Here is my edit-component:

```
const DropdownRessortEdit = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {dropdownRessort, isLoading, isError, message} = useSelector((state)=>state.dropdownRessort);
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [data, setData] = useState({
        lis: [],
        videos:[
                {
                    iframe:"",
                    ressort:"",
                    theme:"",
                    title:"",
                },
                {
                    iframe:"",
                    ressort:"",
                    theme:"",
                    title:"",
                },
                {
                    iframe:"",
                    ressort:"",
                    theme:"",
                    title:"",
                }, 
        ],
        themen:[],

    })
    const {lis, videos, themen} = data;


    useEffect(()=>{
        if(isError){
            window.alert(message);
        }
            dispatch(getDropdownRessort(id));

            return ()=>{
                dispatch(reset());
            }
        
    }, [dispatch, isError, message, id]);

   
    const updateData = (value)=>{
        return setData((prev) =>{
            return { ...prev, ...value}
        })
    }
    const onSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const updateDropdownRessortData = {
            lis,
            videos,
            themen,
        }
        dispatch(updateDropdownRessort(updateDropdownRessortData));
    }
    if(isLoading){
        return <Spinner/>
    }
  return (
   
    <Container>
        <Navbar/>
        <TitleHolder>
            <Title>Update DropdownRessort</Title>
        </TitleHolder>
        <ContentHolder>
            <UpdateForm onSubmit={onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
                    {dropdownRessort.length > 0 && <DataHolder>
                    {dropdownRessort.map((item)=>(
                    <div key={item._id}>
                        <Label htmlFor="name">Name</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="name" id="name" value={item.name} onChange={(e)=>updateData({name: e.target.value})}/>
                        <Label htmlFor="lis">MenüPunkte</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="lis" id=""lis value={item.lis.join(", ")} onChange={(e)=>updateData({lis: e.target.value})}/>
                        <VideoWrapper>
                            <VideoSection>
                            <Label htmlFor="ressortvideo_1_iframe">Video 1 update</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="ressortvideo_1_iframe" id="iframe" value={item.videos[0].iframe} onChange={(e)=>updateData({iframe: e.target.value})}/>
                            <Label htmlFor="ressort">Ressort</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="ressort" id="ressort" value={item.videos[0].ressort} onChange={(e)=>updateData({ressort: e.target.value})}/>
                            <Label htmlFor="theme">Thema</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="theme" id="theme" value={item.videos[0].theme} onChange={(e)=>updateData({theme: e.target.value})}/>
                            <Label htmlFor="title">title</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="title" id="title" value={item.videos[0].title} onChange={(e)=>updateData({title: e.target.value})}/>
                        </VideoSection>
                        <VideoSection>
                            <Label htmlFor="ressortvideo_2_iframe">Video 2 update</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="ressortvideo_2_iframe" id="iframe" value={data.videos[1].iframe} onChange={(e)=>updateData({iframe: e.target.value})}></Input>
                            <Label htmlFor="ressort">Ressort</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="ressort" id="ressort" value={item.videos[1].ressort} onChange={(e)=>updateData({ressort: e.target.value})}/>
                            <Label htmlFor="theme">Thema</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="theme" id="theme" value={item.videos[1].theme} onChange={(e)=>updateData({theme: e.target.value})}/>
                            <Label htmlFor="title">title</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="title" id="title" value={item.videos[1].title} onChange={(e)=>updateData({title: e.target.value})}/>
                        </VideoSection>
                        <VideoSection>
                            <Label htmlFor="ressortvideo_3_iframe">Video 3 update</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="ressortvideo_3_iframe" id="iframe" value={item.videos[2].iframe} onChange={(e)=>updateData({iframe: e.target.value})}></Input>
                            <Label htmlFor="ressort">Ressort</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="ressort" id="ressort" value={item.videos[2].ressort} onChange={(e)=>updateData({ressort: e.target.value})}/>
                            <Label htmlFor="theme">Thema</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="theme" id="theme" value={item.videos[2].theme} onChange={(e)=>updateData({theme: e.target.value})}/>
                            <Label htmlFor="title">title</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="title" id="title" value={item.videos[2].title} onChange={(e)=>updateData({title: e.target.value})}/>
                        </VideoSection>
                        </VideoWrapper>
                        <Label htmlFor="themen">Themen</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="themen" id="themen" value={item.themen} onChange={(e)=>updateData({themen: e.target.value})}/>
                        <ButtonHolder>
                            <UpdateButton type="submit">Update</UpdateButton>
                        </ButtonHolder>
                    </div>
                ))}
                    </DataHolder>  
                }  
            </UpdateForm>
        </ContentHolder>
        <Footer/>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default DropdownRessortEdit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove **dispatch** from the dependencies in *useEffect* hook.

Because you want to fetch **dispatch** only when the component mount, not each time **dispatch** is changed.

So, in your code case, it will change **dispatch** which will re-trigger the hook which will fetch **dispatch** again which will change **dispatch** causes the hook to re-trigger and so on .. causing **Infinity Loop**.

Comment: Thank you Omar, but that not works. VS-Code throws the error, that I have to input dispatch in the dependencies or should delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put dispatch in a `React.useCallback` function as shown in this  example [w3school React.useCallback](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecallback.asp)

Comment: Thank you FaFa, but that not works. I tried it, with dispatch and with getDropdownRessort, but it throws an error or changes nothing.